# Tamura's coarseness textural feature

Tags: image-processing, textures, feature-detection, feature-extraction, texture2d

I am making used of a Tamura texture feature extraction from a library (JFeatureLib).

Tamura feature is an approach that explores texture representation from a different angle since it is motivated by the psychological studies on human visual perception of textures. One of its most important feature is **coarseness** (the other being brightness and contrast).

I am having difficulties with understanding the real meaning of the coarseness feature. From the literature I found that a coarse texture consists of a small number of large primitives, while a fine texture contains a large amount of small primitives. A more precise definition might be:

> The higher the coarseness value is, the rougher is the texture. If
>   there are two different textures, one macro texture of high coarseness
>   and one micro texture of low coarseness, the macro texture is
>   considered.

However, I cannot see any relation between the coarseness value and the roughness of the image.

Example: in my opinion the coarseness value of the images below should increase from left to right. However, I am getting the following coarseness values:

`1.93155, 3.23740, 2.40476, 3.11979 (left to right)`.

[image: According to my coarseness should increase from left to right]

I am finding it quite strange that coarseness_2 is higher than coarseness_3 and coarseness_4. Even worst, for the following images I am getting the coarseness values (almost the complete opposite):

`7.631, 8.821, 9.0664, 10.564 (left to right)`
[image]

I tested with several other other images..these are just two of them.

I know that my interpretation coarseness may be too literal, but again Tamura is said to extract (unlike many other features) in a way that correspond to the human visual system. Am I misunderstanding the real meaning of coarseness or is it a problem of accuracy with the Tamura feature that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Coarseness has a direct relationship to scale and repetition rates and was
seen by Tamura et al as the most fundamental texture feature. An image will
contain textures at several scales; coarseness aims to identify the largest size at which a texture exists, even where a smaller micro texture exists.